# Parsing String based on Order of Occurence

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have data like the SampleDf below, and I'm trying to create code that would pick off the first 'Avg','Sum' or 'Count' that it runs in to in each string and put that in a new column 'Agg'.  The code I have below almost does it but it has a hierarchy.  So in the code I have below if Count comes before Sum it still puts Sum in the 'Agg' column.  I have an OutputDf below showing what I'm hoping to get.

```
Sample Data:

SampleDf=pd.DataFrame([['tom',"Avg(case when Value1 in ('Value2') and [DateType] in ('Value3') then LOS end)"],['bob',"isnull(Sum(case when XferToValue2 in (1) and DateType in ('Value3') and  [Value1] in ('HM') then  Count(LOS) end),0)"]],columns=['ReportField','OtherField'])

Sample Output:

OutputDf=pd.DataFrame([['tom',"Avg(case when Value1 in ('Value2') and [DateType] in ('Value3') then LOS end)",'Avg'],['bob',"isnull(Sum(case when XferToValue2 in (1) and DateType in ('Value3') and  [Value1] in ('HM') then  Count(LOS) end),0)",'Sum']],columns=['ReportField','OtherField','Agg'])


Code:
import numpy as np

    SampleDf['Agg'] = np.where(SampleDf.SQLTranslation.str.contains("Sum"),"Sum",
                              np.where(SampleDf.SQLTranslation.str.contains("Count"),"Count",
                                      np.where(SampleDf.SQLTranslation.str.contains("Avg"),"Avg","Nothing")))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick and dirty attempt at this problem would be writing a function that returns:
- any term of interest, i.e. ['Avg','Sum','Count'], occurring first, if it's present in the string
- or `None`, if there is no such:

```
import re
terms = ['Avg','Sum','Count']
def extractTerms(s, t=terms):
    s_clean =  re.sub("[^\w]|[\d]"," ", s).split()
    s_array = [w for w in s_clean if w in t]
    try:
        return s_array[0]
    except:
        return None
```

Proof if terms in the string:

```
SampleDf['Agg'] = SampleDf['OtherField'].apply(lambda s: extractTerms(s))
SampleDf

ReportField OtherField  Agg
0   tom Avg(case when Value1 in ('Value2') and [DateType] in ('Value3') then LOS end)   Avg
1   bob isnull(Sum(case when XferToValue2 in (1) and DateType in ('Value3') and [Value1] in ('HM') then Count(LOS) end),0)  Sum
```

Proof if terms are not in the string:

```
SampleDf['Agg'] = SampleDf['OtherField'].apply(lambda s: extractTerms(s))
SampleDf

ReportField OtherField  Agg
0   tom foo None
1   bob isnull(Sum(case when XferToValue2 in (1) and DateType in ('Value3') and [Value1] in ('HM') then Count(LOS) end),0)  Sum
```

Comment: Sorry, I clicked the green check mark.  I'm not up on all the customs with stackoverflow.  The check means I'm confirming the answer worked right?  What does an upvote mean?  I went ahead and gave it an upvote.  Definitely appreciate the tip!